# What type of Azure resource can run powershell and have a file system or storage local to the system?

Tags: azure, powershell, file, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

What type of Azure resource can run powershell and have a file system or storage local to the system?

I have a powershell script that needs to:

1. Clone a github repo to local storage
2. Run powershell script against local storage files
3. Return/download an excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [Azure Devops Pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/). That's self explanatory, I guess. You could use Azure Functions, but they have somewhat poor powershell support.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Thank you.